# Iterating through Outlook Emails with a specific subject

Tags: c#, outlook

I am currently working on the below `method` which iterates through emails in my `Inbox`, but wonder how to `filter` them to focus on the ones with `static subject` such as : `nice weather`. Following searches I've thought `folders.Items.Restrict()` could help, however I've got  `condition is not valid` on `var fi = folder.Items.Restric("weather")`. I've also tried 
`var fi = folder.Items.Find("[Subject] = weather")`, to ensure the condition is valid,... but it ends up with no improvement.

Thanks in advance

```
static void IterateMessages(Outlook.Folder folder)
    {
        string[] extensionsArray = {".csv"};
        //var fi = folder.Items;
        var fi = folder.Items.Restrict("weather");

        if (fi != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in fi)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem mi = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
                var attachments = mi.Attachments;
                if (attachments.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(basePath)
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
                    }

                    // Loop through each attachment
                    for (int i = 1; i <= mi.Attachments.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Processing: {0}", mi.Attachments[i].FileName);
                        mi.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(basePath);
                        Console.WriteLine("Attachment: {0}" + " Saved to Path", mi.Attachments[i].FileName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Restrict` parameter seems to be in a wrong format. Try this:

```
var fi = folder.Items.Restrict("@SQL=\"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject\" like '%weather%'";
```

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb611267.aspx)

Comment: @Thanks `diiN_` for the tip. Best,